# Visual Studio 2017 Suggestion List only showing Snippets

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

### PROBLEM

---

I'm on Windows 10 (November TH2 build) using **Visual Studio 2017 v15.1.26403.7**, and I'm not sure whether this problem happens in earlier releases but I noticed that the only way to show snippets in the suggestion list in both C# and VB.NET text editors is by enabling this option:

[image]

However, the weird problem is that after the option is activated, IntelliSense brokes and it only show snippets:

[image]

...as you can see, there is ANY other kind of built-in member suggestion, just snippets, so time-saving programming using IntelliSense is totally lost.

### QUESTION

---

I'm missing something?, it is a bug or is my configuration wrong?. Is there any way I can set the damn intellisense behavior to show normal suggestions plus snippets?, I mean these normal suggestions:

[image]

...plus snippets.

This is my settings file for Visual Studio 2017 (you can import it in your Visual Studio to test it):

http://www.mediafire.com/file/5g2w8j9f6floj19/CurrentSettings.vssettings

Comment: I did a new fresh reinstall, and now I can say this is a BUG. someone can report it to Microsoft devs???. IntelliSense is broken for both C# and VB when the user activates the "Always include snippets" in the options of the VB code editor, it only shows snippets (for C# too, I insist), and it seems the only way to restore normal behavior is reinstalling VS again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback and I tested it on my side with the same VS version, but my result has little differences as yours. Enable ‘Always include snippets’ for both C# and Basic and save it, then type ‘m’ in the *.vb file or *.cs file, the List members only display sinppets in the *.vb file and display normally in the *.cs file, please check the following screenshot:
[image]

I have already reported this issue to the VS Product Team, please see this: [VS 2017 (version: 26403.7): Enable Tools>Options>Text Editor>Basic>Intellisense>Always include snippets and the list members only display the snippets, not includes other types](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/53425/vs-2017-version-264037-enable-toolsoptionstext-edi.html)

You can vote it and add a comment, then please pay patiently to waiting for the response from the VS Product Team Engineers. Sorry for this inconvenience and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: It is awesome to find helper people from the MSFT team in StackOverflow. Thankyou for your time and effort reporting the issue. About C#, maybe I got confussed while mixing configurations, now I tested it again and it seems you have reason, the C# suggestion list works right. PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, it's my pleasure :)